# How many solution exist for $\sin(x^e)/\cos(x) - 2 = 0$?

Tags: trigonometry, matlab, math-software

Here I am trying to find how many solutions exist for the equation in the range $(0,\pi/2)$.
$\sin(x^e)/\cos(x) - 2 = 0$

Solving it through the graph is easy so shall I draw the graph of $\sin(x^e)$ and $\cos (x)$ and compare those two? or I need to include some other thing as well in the graph?

What can be my matlab code to solve this equation ?
Can I solve it using

```
x = 0:0.01: pi/2;
y = sin(x^e);
z = cos(x);
plot(x,y,x,z)
```

How to include $-2$ in this code?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If you can graph it, why not get the graph of $sin(x^e)/cos(x) -2$?

Answer (score -1):

In[5]:= Plot[f[x], {x, 0, Pi/2},
Ticks -> {{Pi/6, Pi/3, Pi/2}, Automatic}]
Plot the graph and see that there are two zeros: One around 1.07974 and one around 1.49678.
Use Newtons method to get as many digits as you desire, e. g. 30:
x=N[11/10,30];
For[n = 1, n <= 6, n++,
Print[N[x, 30]];
x = x - f[x]/f'[x]]
This will deliver 1.0797390735632027377559062453.
The same with initial value x=N[15/10,30]: This will deliver 1.4967796651840889289769323.
Hope this is precise enough for you.